# Show that $f'(c) +9 \int_{0}^{1/3} f(x) \, dx = 0$ for some $c$ if $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, means

> Let $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a differentiable function such that
>   $$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx = 0 \, . $$
>   Prove that there exists a $c \in (0, 1)$ such that
>   $$ f'(c) +9 \int_{0}^{1/3} f(x) \, dx = 0 \, . $$

I think that the solution of this problem can be obtained by applying the mean value theorem for integrals. Since the integral of $f$ on $[0, 1]$ is $0$, we obtain that
$$
0 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, dx=f(a) (1-0) = f(a) 
$$
for some $a\in (0, 1)$. Next
$$
0 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,  dx=\int_{0}^{1/3} f(x) \, dx + \int_{1/3}^{1}f(x) \, dx \, ,
$$
so we have to prove that there exists a point $c \in (0, 1) $ such that
$$
f'(c) = 9 \int_{1/3}^{1}f(x) \, dx \, .
$$
From now on I don't have any idea. I just verified that for the function $f(x)  =2x-1$, the assertion is true.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function
$$
 F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt
$$
satisfies $F(0) = F(1) = 0 $, so that
$$
 g(x) =  F(x) - \frac 9 2 x(1-x) F(\frac 13)
$$
satisfies $g(0) = g(1/3) = g(1) = 0$. (The idea is to subtract from $F$ the quadratic polynomial which interpolates $F$ at $x = 0$, $x= 1/3$, and $x= 1$.)

Repeated application of Rolle's theorem gives $g''(c) = 0$ for some $c  \in (0, 1)$, and that is the desired conclusion because
$$
 g''(x) =  F''(x) + 9 F(\frac 1 3) =  f'(x) + 9 \int_0^{1/3} f(x)\, dx \, .
$$

---

If we replace $1/3$ by an arbitrary $a \in (0, 1)$ then the same method gives the existence of an $c\in (0, 1)$ such that
$$
 f'(c) + \frac{2}{a(1-a)} \int_0^a f(x) \, dx = 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Sheer elegance and clarity of thought! Pat comes the answer for any correctly worded question from someone or other. This exchange is a real boon for learners and learning.

Comment: Very impressive. And thanks for the explanation on genesis of function $g$. +1